# Codeigniter - redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-url

I have problem redirecting from `index` to the functions `logotyp` or `tiskoviny`. When I write to the browser (`localhost/my_page/sluzby/logotyp`) it works but it show without CSS (this is the second problem). The `URL Helper` is auto-loaded.

```
class Sluzby extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('uri');
        $this->load->model('sluzby_model');
        $this->load->model('pages');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        redirect('sluzby/logotyp');
    }

    public function logotyp()
    {
        $data['nadpis'] = "SomeText";
        $this->basic_template->view('basic', 'sluzby_view',$data);
    }

    public function tiskoviny()
    {
        $data['nadpis'] = "SomeText";
        $this->basic_template->view('basic', 'sluzby_view',$data);
    }
}
```

The browser shows me this error when I want to redirect from index:

```
<p>Severity: Warning<br>
Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\dsvision\application\controllers\sluzby.php:1)<br>
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php<br>
Line Number: 542</p>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, make sure there is no white space (spaces, tabs, new lines etc.) before the opening `<?php` tag in your controller. If you have a closing `?>` tag, then this can be removed, as it can often cause issues with `redirect`.

---

In this case, if you aren't concerned about having the function's name in the URL (this will not change the URL to show the function that you are calling (`logotyp()`) in the URL, whereas the `redirect` function would)/refreshing the page, then you could just call the relevant function directly in your `index()` function:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->logotyp();
}
```

---

For your second issue (CSS not loading); it is probably occuring because the link to its path is incorrect. Using the `base_url` function from CodeIgniter's `URL Helper`  you can easily generate the correct path. I don't know where your CSS file(s) is located, but for this example I'll assume that, relative to the site root, it is here: `assets/css/style.css`. Simply add the path relative to web root as so:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/style.css"); ?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[link_tag()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag) in the `HTML Helper`can also help with the generation of stylesheet links.

Comment: Thanks for help. Your index example is better and it is what I want. When I use your index example, css works well but when I go to "sluzby/logotyp" it dont work.

Comment: No problem! What does the `link` to your CSS look like in the `view` file that you load?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url() ?>assets/style/main.css" type="text/css"> `

Comment: You need to `echo` `base_url()` and you're missing the `;` after it too. Try to replace your `href="..."` with this: `href="<?php echo base_url("assets/style/main.css"); ?>"`

Comment: I try it but it also dont works.

Comment: If you load the web page in your browser and _view source_, what does the CSS link look like?

Comment: It show only `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/main.css"> 
`

Comment: Have you set the `base_url` value in `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: Yes, I have and still doesnt work.

Comment: I dont know but it works now. Thank ou very much for your help.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it's working. If you've found an answer useful (whether it's mine or someone else's), please could you consider [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Nice answer +1, just one thing: when you use `$this->logotyp();`, the URL in the browser *won't* change (for the good and for the bad of it), don't forget that.

Comment: Thanks, @Shomz! Yeah, you're totally correct. I did try to at least allude to that when I said: _'if you aren't concerned about having the function's name in the URL...'_ ; but I probably should have made that point more transparent.

Comment: I've edited my answer to further explain the URL situation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have some blank space in your controller... Make sure you remove it and that the file begins with `<?php`. You also can't output anything before the redirect (no views, no echos)...

Comment: Thanks for help. It was really BOMs in files.

Comment: No problem, didn't realize you were using UTF-8. And about the non-working CSS, just make sure you use absolute paths (`base_url("path_to_css");` might help).